# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Widget>'

Tags: flutter, widget

I have an issue that I tried to solve and read lots of answer relative to it.
But I just don't understand what I have to do to make it work.

I'd like display a list of themes object and it's an async function because themes come from an api call.
All of that to create a custom gridView, so I understand well I have to use a FutureBuilder, but I got this error message even when I use it :

[image]

My code looks like that :

```
 GridView.count(
   crossAxisCount: 2,
   children: <Widget>[
      FutureBuilder<Widget>(
          future: themeColorList.buildCustomGrid(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Widget> snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData)
                print("snapshot.data : ${snapshot.data}");
                return snapshot.data;
            return Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
      )
   ]
 )
```

The function called :

```
 buildCustomGrid() async {
    List<ProjectTheme> themeList = await constructTheme();

    List.generate(themes.length, (index) {
       return Container(
         child: Center(
           child: Text(themeList[index].themeName),
         ),
      color: themeList[index].themeColor,
  );
});
```

}

Pretty sure I miss something, I tried to replace 'Future Widget' by 'Future List Widget' (because it's actually a List which is created) but the error is the same, just the second part is replaced by 'Future List Widget'.

Could you please help me?

So I have a begin of something (which not display error anymore).
I had to make something like this :

```
GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  children: <Widget>[
     FutureBuilder<List<Widget>>(
        future: themeColorList.buildCustomGrid(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Widget>> snapshot){
         if(snapshot.hasData) {
            for(int i = 0; i< snapshot.data.length; i++) {
             print("snapshot.data : ${snapshot.data[i]}");
             return snapshot.data[i];
            }
          }
          return Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      )
    ]
)
```

And this :

```
Future<List<Widget>> buildCustomGrid() async {
  List<ProjectTheme> themeList = await constructTheme();

  return List.generate(themes.length, (index) {
    return Container(
     child: Center(
        child: Text(themeList[index].themeName),
     ),
    color: themeList[index].themeColor,
  );
 });
}
```

Of course it only displays the first list element, which is not good either. Have to see how to deal with it.

Comment: If you try giving a List<Widget> when a Widget is expected, that is an issue. Try declaring the return Type on buildCustomGrid(), your IDE should give you some pointers when it comes to datatypes

Comment: I edit my post with the corrections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a full working code for you:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class ProjectTheme {
  String themeName;
  Color themeColor;

  ProjectTheme({this.themeName, this.themeColor});
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<List<ProjectTheme>> getThemes() async {
    List<ProjectTheme> themeList = [
      ProjectTheme(themeName: "red", themeColor: Colors.red),
      ProjectTheme(themeName: "green", themeColor: Colors.green),
      ProjectTheme(themeName: "blue", themeColor: Colors.blue),
    ];
    return themeList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: FutureBuilder<List<ProjectTheme>>(
          future: getThemes(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<List<ProjectTheme>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData)
              return GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                children: snapshot.data
                    .map(
                      (theme) => Container(
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(theme.themeName),
                        ),
                        color: theme.themeColor,
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              );
            return Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          },
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Mainly you put the GridView inside the FutureBuilder.
I refactored also the "buildCustomGrid" method to not return Widgets as it should be.

Hope it can help!

Comment: Waw, thank you so much, it works perfectly like this.
Thank you to take the time to make it, and thank's to all for help. Great community.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to delete "Widget" from your builder? Because it can see it as class and that can be the reason of your error

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: themeColorList.buildCustomGrid(),
```

or use dynamic instead of:

```
FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
          future: themeColorList.buildCustomGrid(),
```